# Does the ICT Short Term visa allow multiple entry?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, working-visas

I am from India and currently in the UK with an **ICT Tier 2 Short Term VISA**.

My COS Start Date is Oct 15, 2013 and end date is Oct 14 2014.

For my marriage I am planning to go India in the week of Jul 3rd and return during the last week of July.

Is it possible to enter the UK again?

Some people say it is not possible, they say I have to enter 3 months before visa expiry.

Comment: *If I can enter, shall I process the visa for my spouse and bring her by Auguest?* I think the visa for your spouse might be better asked in a [separate question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 5):

Here is the [UK border agency's guide](https://contact-ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/working/tier2/ict/) for the Intra-Company Transfer Tier 2 visa. You can download the policy guidance PDF from the link on the right hand side of the page.

Page 52 of that PDF says the following:

> **Absences from the UK**
>   223. The UK, Channel Islands, Isle of Man and Republic of Ireland form a common travel
>   area. If you leave this area while you are employed in the UK (for example, for holidays,
>   business trips or a secondment overseas), you do not need to make a new application to
>   return to the UK unless your leave expires or lapses.
>   224. Please note that if you have been assigned a multiple entry Certificate of Sponsorship, this does not override the rules on ceasing to work for your sponsor which are described in paragraph 229 below.
>   225. If you have been granted entry clearance, or leave to remain for more than six months,
>   your leave will not lapse when you leave the common travel area if you continue to be
>   employed by, and have not ceased working for your sponsor for a period of one calendar
>   month or more (see paragraph 229 below), unless your leave passes its expiry date or you
>   stay outside the UK for more than two years.
>   226. However, if you do not have entry clearance or you have leave to remain which was
>   granted for less than six months, your leave will lapse if you leave the common travel area.
>   227. It is important to make sure that if you are travelling overseas for any reason that you fully understand the implications of your leave lapsing or expiring while you are overseas.

Comment: Thank you. What about processing a dependent visa for my spouse? Will she able to come by Aug here? I heard, in order to process her visa i should have 90 days valid UK visa at that time. Mean she should enter UK before Jul 15th?